# Create tree node in c, hard code the tree

Tags: c

The program that I want achieve here is to construct a tree by hard coding, and then print out the hard code tree. I start with a struct which contain a object name, a question, and a yes or no node that point to the same struct. In the main method, i tried to construct the struct step by step. But I believe that is not the right way of creating a tree with node.

Description of my design: It s a game between computer and user, the computer ask for the question, and then the user answer it with yes or no, and the computer will guess for the object.

```
                  Start here
                       |
                       v
              Does it have a tail?
             /yes               no\
            v                      v
       a pangolin         Is it flat, round and edible?
                              /yes               no\
                             v                      v
                        a pizza                    Pete




#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//object name as key, questions as value
struct node {
  char *objectname;// a string declaration to hold an object-name (which may be NULL)
  char *question;// a string declaration to hold a question (which may be NULL)
  struct node *yes_ptr; // only NULL for objects
  struct node *no_ptr; // only NULL for objects

};

typedef struct node thenode;

thenode *objectname = NULL;
thenode *question =NULL;

void nodePrint(struct node *ptr){

if(ptr->objectname == NULL)
{
    printf("Object : [NOTHING]" );
    printf("Question : %s", ptr->question);
    printf("Yes : &s", ptr->yes_ptr);
    printf("No : &s", ptr->no_ptr);

}else {
    printf("Object : %s", ptr->objectname);
    printf("Question : [NOTHING]");
}
}

int main(argc, **argv){
//if ((new_obj = malloc(sizeof(thenode))) == NULL) { abort(); }

thenode a={NULL, "Does it have a tail?", "a pangolin", "pete"};
thenode b={"a pizza",NULL, NULL, NULL};
//thenode c={NULL, "Is it flat, round and edible?", "a pizza", "pete"};
//thenode c={NULL, "Can you dip it in your tea? ", "biscuit", "a pizza"};
struct node *ptr = &thenode;
nodePrint(&a);
nodePrint(&b);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the "constant" data in an array, including pointers.

```
thenode thenodes[] =
/* 0 */ {{ NULL, "Does it have a tail?", thenodes+1,thenodes+2}
/* 1 */ ,{ "a pangolin", NULL,NULL,NULL}
/* 2 */ ,{ NULL, "Is it flat, round and edible?", thenodes+3 , thenodes+4 }
/* 3 */ ,{"a pizza",NULL, NULL, NULL}
/* 4 */ ,{ "pete", NULL,NULL,NULL}
        };

void nodePrint(struct node *ptr){

if (!ptr) return;
    printf("{" );
if (ptr->objectname == NULL) {
    printf("Object : [NOTHING]" );
    printf("Question : %s", ptr->question);
    printf("Yes : " ); nodePrint(ptr->yes_ptr);
    printf("No : "); nodePrint(ptr->no_ptr);

    }else {
    printf("Object : %s", ptr->objectname);
    printf("Question : [NOTHING]");
    }
    printf("}" );
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
struct node *ptr = thenodes;

nodePrint(ptr);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider implementing your tree as an array! This scheme will take up more memory (array size of `2^n` rather than a set of pointers of size `n`), however, I suspect coding the tree itself will become simpler. You could refactor it into an actual "tree" structure later.

You can find plenty of places on the internet describing how to do this. But say you have a tree like this:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \
D   E
```

Your array representing the tree would look like this:

tree = [A, B, C, D, E]

For each node in position `n` of the array, the left child would be located in position `(2n + 1)` and the right child would be in `(2n + 2)`.

So, given your tree - that you have presumably already created, perhaps by hand - you would know exactly where in the array to place each node (`tree[n] = struct node`) and you would easily be able to traverse it. You could even have a file where each line is a "node" of the tree, and the line number is the same as the array position.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you want to achieve, but:
this

```
typedef struct node thenode;
```

defines user type, which means, you are not declaring a variable of type struct node, but you are declaring new type which IS struct node.

this

```
thenode *objectname = NULL;
```

does not set inner variable objectname of thenode to NULL, this declares a new pointer to variable of type thenode which you previously defined.

this

```
struct node *ptr = &thenode;
```

declares a new pointer to node and assigns the address of !type! thenode to it. (I sincerely hope that this is not compilable).

I recomend looking at some tutorial describing dynamic memory allocation in C. It should look like this:

```
typedef struct {
   ...
}
thenode;

int main () {
   thenode *node;
   ...
   if ((node = malloc(sizeof(thenode))) == NULL) fail_somehow();
   ...
   node->something = something;
   ...
   free(node);
   ...
}
```